# What species is this orc in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-identification

This brute shows up in Legends [*Star Wars: Republic: Emissaries to Malastare*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic:_Emissaries_to_Malastare) and I could never find the name of his species.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to remember which issue?

Comment: There are breakdowns of the issues where people have tried to list species, etc.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots From my copy of the TPB, it looks like this character appears in issue 17 of Star Wars (1998), as a henchman of Kyood Vurd. Vurd refers to him as a "thugling" and mentions that he thought he was immune to mind-tricks, but was wrong. No other information on the species is evident from the issue's dialogue.

Comment: Why did you refer to it as an orc?

Comment: @PeterNielsen Because it clearly *is* an orc?

Comment: How long has the term "orc" been around, though? Didn't Tolkien invent it?